# Since 19.10 upgrade suspected graphics problem ACPI PCI ERROR

Tags: upgrade, graphics, acpi, 19.10, pci

[image][image]Since updating to 19.10 I've had a problem with the screen going blank after I log in. For a brief moment unusual colours flash and multi coloured pixels appear at the top of the screen before it goes black and stays that way. After rebooting many many times the usual desk top appears. But any graphics that move or change have large clusters of multi coloured pixels surrounding them, making it impossible to read what is being displayed. It's strange how 19.04 works fine but the upgrade to 19.10 i just can't get to work.

Asus FX705DY Processor
AMD Ryzen 5 3550H
Graphics adapter
AMD Radeon RX 560X (Laptop) - 4096 MB, Core: 1223 MHz, Memory: 1750 MHz, GDDR5, 128-bit connection, Adrenalin 19.3.3, Enduro

Thanks.

Comment: Is your graphic card Nvidia, Intel , or Amd? And whick model of it it is?

Comment: AMD Radeon RX 560X

Comment: Do you have drivers from AMD?

Comment: No that didn't work. Those drivers are for RX 560 and not the RX560X after installing my system crashes. I'm going to go back to 19.04.